# CF7 Wordpress Message Popup error

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

I have a form which is showing `the requested content cannot be loaded.
please try again later.` as a popup when submitted. I do not have a clue what is causing this error. I am new to wordpress.

Everything seems perfect. I am using CF7 Response Message Popup plugin.

Comment: Check your console for errors, and enable debugging iin your `wp-config.php`

Comment: @dingo_d Only one form is making the issue http://alterknitnewyork.com/schedule-a-pickup/. The others in the same site like http://alterknitnewyork.com/ask-a-question/ is working! I am clueless and I am new to wordpress. Help me pease.

Comment: @dingo_d The form is sending the email as expected. And ajax response is also as expected. But the popup is showing the error!

Comment: @dingo_d same error in popup irrespective of the status of the form submission!

Comment: You have several errors in your console. Fix those and maybe your issue will be solved...

Comment: @dingo_d I am very new to wordpress, and this site is not even developed by me. I am just trying to fix that particular form. I am sure the console errors are not anywhere related to this. The form is able to send email. The popup error is same for all status of the form!

Comment: Without much to go on, no one (including me) will be able to help you...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112854/discussion-between-sibidharan-and-dingo-d).